# Fitting a chi2 distribution, estimation of dof, difference with the mean value of the data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, distribution

I have data to process and in theory, I know the distribution of that data - it's chi2.

I know this (data) was produced using sampling from chi2 distr. and I know the parameters used for sampling - e.g. mean value and number of degrees of freedom used in chi2.

But in my case - I need to find out those parameters from "measured data" assuming chi2 distribution. Find the average parameters and the degrees of freedom (estimated values).
[image]

When I am trying to fit this function for the pdf:

```
def chi2_pdf(x, dof, loc = 0, scale=1):
    return chi2.pdf(x, df=dof, loc = loc, scale=scale)
```

I am getting various parameters that are really hard to interpret:
(loc, scale - what is the meaning of those parameters?)
I have assumed that loc stands for the mean value and scale  - some rescaling number - but for my case I have got some unreal numbers that confused me a lot.. E.g. negative loc value and dof much larger than it is in the example data.

**So main question is - How to fit distribution correctly and get reasonable estimates of parameters?**
Maybe I need to rescale the data before fitting and passing them to a function calculating the pdf?

I have tried to use curve-fit to estimate parameters of scipy.stats.chi2.pdf, - see the code below - but don't know how to interpret parameters I have, e.g. as a result I have negative loc or scale values - what are they stand for?

E.g. for provided case:

> Estimated dof, LS: 7793.619571961899
> Estimated scale: 0.1006724349475489
> Estimated loc:-720.5363121803032

Assuming that for the chi2 distribution mean value is the dof (?) - I have completely wrong answer..

How to make sure that the estimated parameters are correct?

Here is a code with the example data and a plot of that data to reproduce:

```
from distfit import distfit
from scipy.stats import chi2
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# getting the data
data_csv_link = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Cs7-dTs6TesVvSNd7g0aJOj4IQqsOuCb'
data_df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(data_csv_link, ' ', header=None)

data = data_df[0].to_list()

print(data)

# plotting the distribution of gg
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hist(data , density=True, bins=50, alpha=0.5, cumulative=False, label = 'Data')

#kernel density estimation of the curve (just for visualization purposes)
#kde = gaussian_kde(data)
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 100)
#ax.plot(x, kde(x), 'b-', label='KDE of data')

# how to find optimal values of average value of parameter I am measuring?
#  & dof for chi-2 assuming that the data is distributed like chi-2?
# if we use scipy.stats - what are the best parameters to fit given data with scipy?
# chi2.pdf(x, dof, scale)

df = 64 # real mean parameter used for generation..
loc = 0
scale = 1

ax.plot(x, chi2.pdf(x, df=df, loc = loc, scale=scale), 'r-', label = 'Estimate curve')

ax.set_title('Distr. of data')
ax.legend()

# try to find using distfit
dist = distfit(distr=['chi2', 'norm'])
results = dist.fit_transform(data_df[0])
dist.plot()
dist.plot_summary()
print(dist.summary)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to fit your data using scipy stats module, and all good. Tried χ<sup>2</sup> as well as Γ distributions.

With Python 3.10.11, Windows 10 x64, code below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import gamma
from scipy.stats import chi2

#%%

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv('distrib_data.csv', header=None)
samp=df[0]

#%%

figprops = dict(figsize=(8., 7. / 1.618), dpi=128)
adjustprops = dict(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.97, top=0.93, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

fig = pylab.figure(**figprops)
fig.subplots_adjust(**adjustprops)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.hist(samp,bins=40,density=True,alpha=0.6,color='grey', label='Data')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()

prms=[]

# Distributions.
dist_names = ['gamma', 'chi2']
for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(samp)
    prms.append(param)
    
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) #
    ax.plot(x, dist(*param).pdf(x), linewidth=4, label=dist_name)

    #ks = scipy.stats.kstest(samp, dist_name, args=param)
    #print((dist_name, ks))

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)

gprms = prms[0]
ag = gprms[0]
locg = gprms[1]
scag = gprms[2]
g = gamma.pdf(x, ag, locg, scag)
ax.plot(x, g, 'bo', label='GAMMA')

c2prms = prms[1]
ac2 = c2prms[0]
locc2 = c2prms[1]
scac2 = c2prms[2]
c2 = chi2.pdf(x, ac2, locc2, scac2)
ax.plot(x, c2, 'r+', label='CHI2')

ax.legend(fontsize=14)

plt.savefig('fitting.png')
```

I got graph

[image]

also plot manually set PDFs (using dots/crosses) using fit parameters. Everything is consistent and looks good.

Γ parameters (a, loc, scale) are

```
(278.9837823140648, -152.91038915852812, 0.7781131175525391)
```

χ<sup>2</sup> parameters

```
(130.2560942599167, -42.346714338480915, 0.8168263418412613)
```

UPDATE

Just a simple check wrt χ<sup>2</sup>

```
np.mean(samp)

64.17055440169463
```

ok, then, expression below should be about 0

```
np.mean(samp) - (ac2*scac2 + locc2)

0.12065976331726347
```

looks ok